# Spawn new child process with own console window

Tags: node.js, spawn

I've got a parent application in node.js which needs to spawn multiple worker applications (also in node.js) applications according to need.

I've already got communication working between them - don't need to use any of the built-in node stuff.

Now the problem is that I'd like each worker process to have it's own console window - since I do a lot of writing to the console and I want to keep an eye on it.

I've looked through the [Node child_process documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options), and it says that by setting options to detached:

> On Windows, setting options.detached to true makes it possible for the child process to continue running after the parent exits. The child will have its own console window.

However when I use my own code

```
const Process = require("child_process").spawn;
Process(process.argv[0], ["myApplicationPath","otherArgs"],{detached: true,stdio: ['ignore']});
```

It doesn't work. The child application does spawn, but no console window turns up.

Comment: I might be super late to the party, but did you find a solution, considering you asked this May '16? Or, better said, can you remember a solution?

Answer (score 9):

I'm a bit late here, but I just had to figure this out as well, so here is the answer for anyone else who is struggling with this:

I managed to spawn my child application in its own console using this:

```
childProcess.spawn("<cmd>", [], {shell: true, detached: true});
```

In addition to the `{detached: true}` what OP is using, I used `{shell: true}`. With the combination of both, I managed to spawn my child application with its own console.